# What method was used to create book illustrations in late 1800s/early 1900s?

Tags: technology, book, printing

There were (and are) many processes for producing printed images that were used in the 1800s, mostly variants of engraving, etching and lithography.

Early books used woodcut images, which are usually distinctive for the relatively coarse style like this:

[image]

For images like the following from an 1911 encyclopaedia, what would have been the technique used?

[image]

It appears that, as opposed to copper or steel engravings or intalglio (think Albrect Dürer) or lithography, the images in such a book are printed by a metal block included in the [forme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forme_(printing)):

[image]

In this case, the printer's mark is probably a re-usable block that can be recycled for other books printed in the same printing house. On the other hand, illustrations from a given book are probably only useful for that book.

Type was bought in bulk from "type foundries" according to the font, variant and size. But the illustrations had to be custom-made for the book. Who did that, and how? What were these block made of? The same kind of [type metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_metal) as the sorts?

My guess (if I had to make one) would be a using a reducing copy milling machine from a paper master provided by the book author and engraving from that into some kind of metal block.

Comment: Based on the time period, I'd guess a photoengraving procedure such as the halftone process of [Frederick Ives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederic_Eugene_Ives), but I don't know enough to determine it with certainty from the photo of the block.